# Undefined variable: $ Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code from youthController:

```
public function index()
{
    $firstProducts=Product::where('publication_status',1)
        ->take(4)
        ->get();
    return View('front-end.home.home',[

        '$firstProducts'=>$firstProducts
    ]);
}
```

this is the code that I'm writing to the home.blade.php

```
@foreach($firstProducts as $firstProduct)
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md2 animated wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset($firstProduct->product_image)}}" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">{{$firstProduct->product_name}}</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                            <h5 class="item_price">TK.{{$firstProduct->product_price}}</h5>
                            <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              @endforeach
```

I'm getting this error:

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: firstProducts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project-youth\resources\views\front-end\home\home.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Undefined variable: firstProducts (0)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code and the error message as text. No one wants to click on those links.

Comment: `'$firstProducts'=>$firstProducts` You don't need `$` in the first part; just `'firstProducts'=>$firstProducts`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
return view('front-end.home.home', ['firstProducts'=> $firstProducts]);
```

Or

```
return view('front-end.home.home', compact('firstProducts'));
```

you don't need to use $